# Clip or Intersection tool - QGIS giving empty files

Tags: qgis, clip, united-kingdom

I am trying to clip an Ordnance Survey Master Map (OSMM) feature based on a polygon created for the sake of clipping which does not have any attributes, but the output is an empty file.

Projection of both the files is similar.

Could you please let me know how to achieve the result either using polygon or if there is any method I can use in QGIS?

Comment: When using _Clip_, are you using the polygon file as the Input vector layer and the OSMM as the Clip layer?

Comment: No Clip layer is a Polygon to which I want to extract the area from OSMM, so OSMM as the Input vector. But I tried both ways.

Comment: Does the output shapefile contain any attributes at all? Infact, does your polygon file contain any attributes (even if the values are NULL)?

Comment: Output shapefile doe not contain anything in the attribute table, polygon file does have an empty attribue table called ID.  Thanks

Comment: Do the layers still overlap the same way when you turn on-the-fly-reprojection **OFF**?

Comment: Is your OSMM layer a line-type shapefile or polygon-type shapefile?

Comment: Yes I turned off the on-the-fly-reprojection and it has not changed the position of the layers

Comment: Perhaps upload your shapefiles to Dropbox or something similar so people can test it.

Comment: Based on some other questions similar to this, it's possible you aren't giving the tool sufficient time to process. If the file you are clipping is very large or complex, it may take an extensive amount of time for the clip operation to process. The first step is creating an empty container file to hold the results, so perhaps you're only seeing that.

Comment: Did this issue get resolved? I have the same issue. I have downloaded numerous datasets from Data BC. I can get them to intersect with ArcMap, but not with QGIS. QGIS generates a shapefile with attributes but no features. However, two shapefiles that I got from a QGIS tutorial site DOES intersect properly. I have put two sample shapefiles at http://vulnerablevancouver.ca/qgis_intersection/. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi,Yes issue is resolved as there was a problem with the intersection. The original file I used to intersect was generated in QGIS and using that further for intersection gave me bad results. I tried creating a shapefile in ArcGIS and used that for intersection which worked.  Later on I also tried in QGIS which worked too somehow.