# Clip tool does not work Qgis

Tags: qgis, vector, clip, vector-grid

Is there any particular reason why I cannot clip in QGIS (2.8)?

I have a Vectorgrid which I created based on another shape - namely a country.
Now I want to clip the vectorgrid to the size of the country.
But, whenever I use the "clip" tool in QGis it gives me an empty output.
It worked just fine before and I do not know what I made differently there...

Here the two files I try to clip.
http://www.file-upload.net/download-10442231/shapes.zip.html

Other Vectortools do not work neither... Basically I have the same problem than this:
[Clip in QGIS 2.4.0 resulting in empty output files](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109698/clip-in-qgis-2-4-0-resulting-in-empty-output-files)

Here are some additional information:
[image: They overlay]
[image: Properties]
[image: Properties]
[image: Project Projection]

Comment: Did you check if there are any topology errors?

Comment: @parallax What are these errors?
I am having one shapefile with an empty attribute table and the other one is a vectorgrid, created of that with 130.000 shapes each with x_min; y_min and x_max; y_max

Comment: @parallax I did Vector >> Geometry >> Check geometry validity but there are no errors

Comment: Ok, there are no errors. I clipped it within QGIS 2.8 and it worked.But it took quite a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright.
QGis requieres several python packages such as NumPy and Matplotlib.
I did not have these packages prior to installing QGis thus I downloaded them and installed them on my machine (very to recommend since the "from hand" installation is kind of hard).

However, I forgot about these packages and wanted to install them again - This time not from the QGis site but with `pip` and/or `setup.py install` since I needed to work in Python with them.
That kind of worked but caused some error messages during the installtion process. Anyway, I still could work with NumPy or Matplotlib in Python, but I think QGis got confused with several versions of these packages on my system.

Luckily, I had a backup on Time Machine prior to installing NumPy and Matplotlib through `pip; setup.py install`.
I rolled up that back up, and here we go - works again!
The good thing is: I can import NumPy and Matplotlib on Python 2.7 as well. So, if you want to use these modules, but not interested in QGis, I still recommend downloading them from the QGis website because that installation there works just fine whereas my "from hand" installation failed terribly.

Answer (score 1):

Within QGIS 2.8 you can choose the following setting:
[image]

Comment: Well thats what I am doing... And it gives me an empty output!

Comment: strange behaviour - even my attribute table isn't empty...

Comment: Thats why i am here...

Comment: Did you try any of the solutions from the other question you linked? Also try to save the borders shape to another file with shorter filename - maybe this helps?

Comment: yep. did not help

Comment: I also tested this on QGIS 2.6.1 and works fine. Do you really need the geometry columns (`XMIN`, `YMIN`, `XMAX`, `YMAX`)? Personally I don't keep these but deleting them does speed up the process (got it clipped in 2 minutes). Otherwise, I would suggest to download a previous QGIS version and repeat the steps. Why it's not working for you could be due to some random bug or QGIS 2.8 wasn't installed completely etc.